# Using Steamcommunity as an OpenID provider to authenticate with Torii

Tags: ember.js, openid, steam, torii

I was wondering how you can use Torii to authenticate users in an ember-cli application. Torii has a lot of providers for OAuth authentications but there are none for OpenID.

I have tried to create a server-side NodeJS application that handles authentication with Steam using Passport, but I'm not sure how to connect that with my Ember app to verify if the user is authenticated and retrieve details about their profile.

Do I have to create a custom authenticator or provider for Torii in order to sign in with Steam? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your question to include your existing code or demonstrate what problem you have encountered. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on asking a good question.

Comment: I don't know the flow for OpenID. But you probably need to make your own custom providers/authenticators with Torii. You can also have a look at [ember-simple-auth](http://ember-simple-auth.com/)